# Unable to write into a file using PHP in sourceforge

Tags: php, fwrite

I want to HTTP POST data to a PHP file which will in-turn write the data into a file. The script I used is as follows,

```
 <?php
    #error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $msglen=strlen($_POST["msgarea"]);
    $msg=$_POST["msgarea"];
    $fp = fopen("dinesh.txt", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $msg); 
     fclose($fp); 
     echo "Data Written -> $msg";
    ?>
```

I am hosting this script file in sourceforge.

I have already just created the empty file dinesh.txt and placed the file in the same directory as that of the script file. But unfortunately its not written in the file.

What is the reason ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check file permission and file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `$_POST["msgarea"]` is not empty and the file is writeable for the user who tries to write it.
And check the logs for errors of course.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
var_dump($_POST["msgarea"]);

$msglen=strlen($_POST["msgarea"]);
$msg=$_POST["msgarea"];
$fp = fopen("dinesh.txt", 'w');
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg); 
fclose($fp); 
if ($result) {
    echo "Data Written -> $result";
} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are writing in read-only webspace, check file permissions and path

Answer (score 1):

From: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/ticket/2772

> In generally it is not allowed to write to folders and files that reside in the project's web space. If you need to write to the file system you should use the folder named persistent that is on the same level as htdocs.

I use on my computer:

```
$ mkdir persistent
$ chmod 0777 persistent
$ scp -r persistent my_account@web.sourceforge.net:/home/project-web/my_project/
```

And set in PHP:

```
$fp = fopen("../persistent/dinesh.txt", 'w');
```

And it works!

**Edit:**
You can get access for SSH console for 4 hours (https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Shell%20service). And you can go to web directory of your project, make dirs, set privileges, remove files etc. Midnight Commander is available.

Answer (score 0):

you can, check that folder permission, do they have 777 permission

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```